# has_many through association, and multiple search criteria, how can i make this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a multi criteria search form. I want to submit all of the pieces of the search via GET and if they have a value assigned I would like them evaluated. The thing that I'm having trouble grasping is building a query that will allow me to layer more queries on top when you're doing it with a through association.

Just to give you an idea of how my models are set up:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :pieces, :through => :campaigns
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :pieces
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Now, with that model in mind, I'm using the collect method to grab the pieces that have an organization in common.

```
if params.has_key?(:criteria)
    @selected_client = Client.where(:organization => "Org1")
    @pieces = @selected_client.collect{ |c| c.pieces }.flatten
end
```

Is there some way of formatting that query string so that I can narrow @pieces down, a couple more times? Let's say I wanted to use that through association again, to get pieces that have another of the same Client criteria...

Thanks a ton! My brain is a pretzel at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i undestand very well what you're trying to do. If you want to get all pieces matching your client criteria, in rails 3, you can do this :

```
@pieces = Piece.joins(:campaign => :client).where(:clients => {:organization => criteria})
```

to get all pieces belonging to clients from organization "Org1".

You can stack as many where statements as you want to add new conditions, as @Andrew said. **[See this for more information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)**.

Comment: Woohoo! My brain is still dripping out of my ears, but I have several more of these to make, and hopefully by the end of this I'll have the hang of it. It took me a while to get because I had one of my associations set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your first paragraph got cut off, just FYI.

If @pieces is an array, you can use a `find` block to narrow your search further. Although this will put the load on your server CPU rather than the SQL database.

You can stack `where` statements and Rails will automatically create a single query for you. Here is some sample code from the app store section of our website:

```
@platform = params[:platform]
@category = params[:category]
@search   = params[:app_q]

# Get initial SQL, narrow the search, and finally paginate
@apps = App.live

@apps = @apps.where("platform = ?", AppPlatforms.value(@platform)) if AppPlatforms.value(@platform)
@apps = @apps.where("(name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", "%#{@search}%", "%#{@search}%") if @search
@apps = @apps.where("id IN(?)", @cat.apps) if @category && @cat = Category.find_by_id(@category)

@apps = @apps.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => "name")
```

Instead of using `collect` you should be able to use `@selected_client.pieces.where(...)` to narrow your search down via SQL.

I hope this is a point in the right direction!

Comment: Hey there, I played with this for a bit, but didn't quite get it. It's possible that one of my associations being foobed may have caused a problem, but the other solution seemed to work out for me. Thank you so much for the response!